# Access ML-model stored in AzureML Workspace from self-hosted Azure DevOps agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, authorization, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to download a registered ML-model from a specific workspace to a remote agent. I succeed in connecting to the workspace using a "Service Principal" and I can find the model and print its specifications. However, when I try to download it och get its path, I get the error:

"Failed to download file with error: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure"

Performing the same task on "host" (with single-sign in) works just fine. Could this have to do with the permissions given when setting up the agent with PAT?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I needed to add the agents IP-address in the corresponding Storage Accounts Firewall exceptions (where the Workspace/model was stored). For others facing the same problem, this is valid for "Azure Hosted Agents" as well.

Added a task  in the corresponding agent that ECHO:ed its own IP-address, which I then added to the firewall exceptions. [Location of Firewall settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY53w.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new PAT with full access and then run the `config.cmd` again.

[image]

In addition, please check if you are running a firewall or a proxy on the bastion host. If you're running an agent in a secure network behind a firewall, make sure the agent can initiate communication with the URLs and IP addresses mentioned in below documents.

- [What URLs does the agent need to communicate with?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with)
- [How do I configure the agent to bypass a web proxy and connect to
  Azure Pipelines?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-configure-the-agent-to-bypass-a-web-proxy-and-connect-to-azure-pipelines)